# Intermittently unable to set cookies in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

My team and I are seeing a pretty weird issue that we can only reproduce in Chrome and even then only intermittently, though we have all gotten into this state multiple times.  Generally the cookies are getting set correctly but every so often we get into this state:

We are setting the cookie in perl and seeing Set-Cookie in the headers:
[set-cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rWL7.png)
(I took out the domain and path here but that is present too - domain=.domain.com; path=/ - It is an actual domain on a server, not localhost or an IP)

Then, this 'session_id' cookie is never getting sent back in the request headers.  The strangest thing is that I can manually set a cookie with a random name in the console with document.cookie = "one=two" but trying to set a cookie with the name of "session_id" the same way does not set. No errors or anything, it just isn't there when looking at the cookies.

It works again when using an incognito window or restarting chrome, but we are worried that our users might end up in this state as well.

Has anyone seen this issue before or have any ideas on what is causing it?  It's really stumping us right now and we really need to get it figured out.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: We see the same thing on our production site since yesterday. Also only in Chrome (so far). Incognito seems to work. We run on MVC.Net and havn't touched cookie/security code for a long time. On my own pc I can even not log out right now. I see the response cookie being returned to the browser, but it just gets ignored..